# FCM & iOS - One Token for 2 different apps on same device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two different iOS apps registered to same Firebase project.

Both are installed to same iOS device.

Both apps have APNS enabled (at sandbox mode), and Firebase enabled.

The Firebase project can push to both apps.

Both apps use their appropriate `GoogleService-Info.plist`s.

Both apps provide different APNS device tokens.

Both apps generate their FCM tokens with `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token(withAuthorizedEntity: "Project's SenderID", scope:kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging, options:["apns_token":deviceTokenAPNS,"apns_sandbox":true], handler:)`

However, for some reason unknown to me, both apps generate *the same FCM token*. And I need this generated FCM token for backend use. And I don't want this use to end up pushing the same message to be received by the wrong app.

> Question: I thought different iOS apps generate different FCM tokens, even if they are installed into same device and belong to same project. So what happened?

Comment: Facing the same issue. How to fix this?

Comment: @abhi1992 I wish I knew.

Comment: You didn't fix it?

Comment: If I knew how to fix this, I would have not asked this in the first place. >_<

Comment: Creating different projects will fix this issue I guess. I don't have any other fix for this.